# how can I align button with inputs

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

That. How can i align this  button with the inputs. I try with percentage but only work in a specific screen. And I am using flexbox in this case, i dont know if is that

[image: how can align all this]

```css
.Contact-form{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 45%;
}

.Contact-input{
    width: 90%;
    padding: .9em;
    border: 0;
}

.Contact-input:focus{
    outline: none;
}

.btn{
    width:  100%;
    background-color: #da2929;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 1px #671212;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="Contact-form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" class="Contact-input" required="true">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Apellido" class="Contact-input">
  <input type="email" placeholder="correo@ejemplo.com" class="Contact-input" required="true">
  <input type="submit" value="Subscribeme" class="Contact-input btn">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding `box-sizing: border-box;`on `.Contact-input`. I'll probably need to add the necessary prefixes for each browser.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your input button is .btn, it carries a width of 100% while your text inputs carry a width of 90%, which is why there is a discrepancy.

You could handle this two ways
1) remove the width declarations entirely from .btn and .Contact-input (which would allow them both to take up the full 100% width), or
2) set both elements explicitly to have the same width

Comment: this happens when I put both in width 100% [image](http://i.imgur.com/XUvXgdN.png) thanks for the help @Jay